# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Gradle not working on bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gradle, build, scripting

I'm trying to figure out how to use gradle on bash on Ubuntu on Windows, but all the tutorials assume that everything goes smoothly and I keep getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
```

I tried to post code from the stacktrace here, but it was impossible to format as code on this form. The "code" button doesn't do anything and I wasn't even able to use 4 spaces in parts of my code to manually format it. I am extremely intelligent, but I have never used gradle successfully before (and this form being wonky is double frustrating) and I've worked dozens of hours to find a useful tutorial for someone like me who has run many complex programs in compilers, but never used a build tool before. Frankly, no one has ever told me what a build tool is useful for (other than basic scripting which I understand) and the information is hidden very well online. My programs run fine without a scripting tool, but I know I'm missing something and gradle seems to be essential for some reason, but nearly impossible to learn without expert guidance since all the tutorials leave out essential information. I assume knowledge of ant and maven are taken for granted, but if gradle is as superior as it is touted to be, it would be counterproductive to learn the inferior build tools. Is there any way to learn gradle without wishing for death? Please help.